# Java mmap-buffer memory model

Tags: java, mmap, java-memory-model

Suppose two threads working with single memory mapped buffer concurrently (`java.nio.channels.FileChannel.map()`).

First thread is:

- writing the size of record;
- writing the record itself;
- repeat.

for example

```
ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(READ_WRITE, 0, ...)

buffer.putShort((short) data.length);
buffer.put(data);
```

Reading thread is reading those packets:

```
short size = buffer.getShort();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
buffer.get(bytes);
```

From time to time I get `BufferUnderflowException` from `buffer.get(bytes)` which is reasonable because there is clearly race in this naïve code. Reading can happen after the size is written but before packet is.

*The question is, does write to mmap buffer is volatile?* Can I safely fix the problem just reordering write operation in writing thread, so length of the packet is never visible before the packet itself or some external coordination mechanism should be used?

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misconception. When you get a `BufferUnderflowException`, it implies that there are not enough remaining bytes, which is the difference of `limit` and `position`. Since the size of a mapped byte buffer is fixed right from the point of time you invoked `channel.map`, the actual write has no relevance here. Except, when you are using the same buffer instance in both threads, but then, a) you have to invoke `flip()` between `put` and `get`, b) have to ensure that there is no race regarding the position and limit of this buffer, and c) do not need write the size…

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing related to `volatile` in here. What you have is two writes which need to be atomic. I don't see how reordering write operations would fix anything, and volatile doesn't make things atomic.

You'll need to make sure that read can't be performed before the header and the data are written, so you'll need external synchronization for that.

It's also worth noting that `MappedByteBuffer` depends a lot on the underlying filesystem and OS, so you better make sure that you're not writing brittle code that relies on the native behaviour.

Comment: I don't think I really need atomic update in my case. In my opinion happens-before should be enough. The packet write should happened before packet size.